# how to Add Proxy List to Perl?

Tags: perl, proxy

So my question is kind of hard but i give it a try:

My code is a script that use this website to extract domains from reverse ip address "http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/"

The problem is that whenever i scan until 12 try i cant get results because the website block My IP when i get to 12 search.

So i was trying to find a way to add proxy but i need to change proxy whenever i scan again.

How could I add proxy list and limit the search for 12 per proxy?

this is my code :http://pastebin.com/EY3cy5Vs

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use HTTP::Request;
use LWP::UserAgent;

if($^O =~ /Win/){
    system("cls");
    system("color a");
    system("title Get Sites by : ip");
}else{
    system("clear");
}

print q{

                       *--------------------*
                       *       Get          *
                       *      Sites         *
                       *  result in log.txt *
                       *--------------------*
};

print "\nPut Host or IP (host without http://) :";

my $host = <>;
chomp($host);

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; fr; rv:1.9.1) Gecko/20090624 Firefox/3.5');
$ua->env_proxy;
#proxy
my $response = $ua->get("127.0.0.1");
#proxy
my $zz = $ua->post('http://domains.yougetsignal.com/domains.php',
    {
        remoteAddress => $host,
    }
);

my $resulta = $zz->content;
while ($resulta =~ m/\[([^\]]*)\]/g)
{
    $zeb = $1;
    $zeb =~ m/\"(.*?)\", \"?\"/g;
    open(a, ">>log.txt");
    print a "http://$1/\n";
    close(a);
}

print "\nresult in log.txt";
```

Answer (score 1):

> How could I add proxy list and limit the search for 12 per proxy?

You can't add a list using the environment (i.e `env_proxy`) but you can change the proxy whenever you want with

```
  $ua->proxy(['http','https'],'http://proxy-ip:port');
```

This setting applies then to all requests done with `$ua` until you change the setting again.